# How to access mysql database from Android device without internet connectivity?

Tags: android, mysql

I am implementing an app which has a database that contains millions of values and is located on a PC(Server) . Now provided, I won't have an active internet connection, what option do I have to connect with the mysql database? Is it possible to implement this using a wireless LAN?

Comment: You need to be connected some sort of connection, like wifi. But in production this wont work offcourse.

Comment: what you mean by : in production this wont work?

Comment: How would you connect users to WIFI and to your network ? You need to place you API on some public server

Comment: @MurtazaKhursheedHussain ultimately it will require any sort of connection!

Comment: Thats what I said. @PareshMayani

Comment: yes it is possible to impliment wireless LAN

Comment: provided, there won't be any other wifi available, will setting a hotspot would be a good idea?

Comment: @Ravi have you tried anything similar?

Comment: yes, just make your ip with port number and link of your php api file

Comment: @Ravi , can I have an extended conversation with you via mail or IM ?

Comment: http://LAN_IP_address:8080/apifolder/api/ @shaheen just do that kind bro

Answer (score 0):

My only thought would be to load the data into xml or JSON files if you had to access offline 
although this would not be an efficient or secure way (depending upon what your data is) this may be an option for you

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can connect it without the internet all you have to do is 
start the Wifi hotspot of your mobile device and connect your laptop to the wifi network of your mobile

**the mobile and the PC(server)should be on the same network** 
assuming that you are using XAMPP server go to the folder where you installed XAMPP on PC and search for httpd-xampp config file
inside XAMPP\apache\conf\extra

```
<LocationMatch "^/(?i:(?:xampp|security|licenses|phpmyadmin|webalizer|server-status|server-info))">
   # Require local
ErrorDocument 403 /error/XAMPP_FORBIDDEN.html.var
</LocationMatch>
```

find and comment the Require local

Now grant the privileges to the database user to connect with % ie any host

Open Command Prompt and type ipconfig there you will find the IpV4 address

use that address for the connection string
ie.

```
connection=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://192.168.x.xxx/databasename","username","password");
```

and you can connect get the connection to the database

[Android with mysql connectivity without JSON or PHP](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=q8G1-s6yYKo)
[Android with mysql connectivity](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vVGR2B9FIG0)

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do it using wireless Lan.

check this link: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/varund/2010/09/02/create-a-sql-server-database-on-a-network-shared-drive/